# In Presto SQL, how to extract all substrings followed by a pattern? Each word in the string is separated by space

Tags: presto, regex-lookarounds

Input string: "abc_11234 abc_11235 xyz78763 abc_32342"
Expected output [11234, 11235, 32342]

The goal is trying to get all the substrings after abc_ in each string separated by space.
I've tried using `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(v, 'abc_\s*(.+)')` but the pattern extracts everything after the first abc_

Comment: Maybe `'abc_\s*(\S+)'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT regexp_extract_all(v, 'abc_\s*(\S+)', 1);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k9NUib/1). `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace chars. `1` means the contents of Group 1 are only returned.

See [more about how `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` function works](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html).